# I can't call a web service from a website in visual studio after I close the project

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, visual-studio, localhost

I have followed a procedure i found in books etc.

I create a C# ASP.NET Web Service Project, let's say Service 1

I program the methods and when I run it, I see the methods I've created and the address in the browser is something like:

**http://localhost:2379/Service1.asmx**

Then I create a Web Site in Visual Studio, with C# and I add a WebReference to this address

So, when I create objects like:

**localhost.Service1 obj = new localhost.Service1();**

I can call the methods like this:

**obj.Method1(value);**

So far so good, I create the Website, it debugs, works perfectly

When I close the project and run it again, it no longer works.

Any ideas?

I want to create a website that will run in anyone's computer with visual studio

Answer (score 0):

Check the port of the HTTP server. It seems that you're using the WebDev server (or the dynamic web server from Visual Studio) which assigns a random port.

Debug first the asmx project in order to start the server. Check the port and update the webreference in case it changed.